# Interactively running code during a debugging session in Perl

Tags: perl, debugging

Say my debugger stops at a breakpoint. Is there any way to run/send arbitrary Perl code to the debugger?

For example, say I stop the debugger at a location with the statement:

```
$DB::single = 1
```

I would like to be able to:

1. Type and execute general Perl statements from the debugger prompt
2. Run scripts

Comment: From your questions, it sounds like you want to do some very strange things with the debugger. Would you like to describe the bigger picture so that we can help you better? Running a debugger non-interactively is rarely a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Anything you type in the debugger that isn't recognized as a debugger command is interpreted as perl and run. You can run a file using `require` or `do`, although I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "interactively" run code from another file.

Comment: Hmm, you said that `anything you type in the debugger that isn't recognized as a debugger command is interpreted as Perl and run`, but if I am on the debugger and I type `print "hello";` I don't see `"hello"`. I have also tried with other similar simple statements (e.g. `my $a =2;`  `print $a;` with no luck)

Comment: @user815423426 the first one works fine for me. The second one only doesn't work because a `my` var declared in one line on the debugger doesn't carry over to a later line. `my $a = 2; print $a` on one line also works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, adding a `\n` flushes the buffer. E.g.  `print ("something\n")` outputs all my previous prints and the new one correctly.

Comment: Do you know how I can define variables that carry over to later lines? Is this at all possible? What about modifying the values of existing variables?